# Will SharePoint delete the User Profile and his mysite if User Account is disabled and moved another OU in the same domain?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

What will happen if a user's profile is set to be disabled and moved(from Users OU) to the Disabled Users OU(just another OU)? does SharePoint deletes the user profile and properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you set the User Profile Sync to omit the Disabled User OU, the users will be removed from the import. You can also add the additional check for "disabled" but simply changing OU will work.

Also, ensure that you are regularly running a search crawl of the User Profiles so that the user is removed from Search Results.

Comment: We have two OUs namely - Users & DisabledUsers and both are selected in the UPS sync. We dont have any exclusion filter is set (userAccountControl Bit on equals 2). Now, what will happen if a user's profile is set to be disabled on the Users OU and moved to the DisabledUsers OU? does SharePoint deletes the user profile and properties? For me - those user profiles are no longer found in the User profile Store.

Comment: IIRC you have to set a bitwise filter for disabled. The alternative would be to not include the DisabledUsers in the import settings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your user profile service application is setup.

Check settings here to determine whether user profiles will be removed:

User Profile Service Application > Configure Synchronization Connections > Edit Connection Filters > Exclusion Filter for Users

As for whether my sites will be removed for users removed from the user profile store, it depends on whether the My Site Cleanup Timer Job is running in your farm. You can disable the job if you would like to manually manage my site cleanup.

For more info on the My Site Cleanup Timer Job (2010) see [this great post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx) from Kirk Evans.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will sync the ou's you have chosen to sync, so if you do not select disabled users ou, then any user moved into that OU will not be synched and their profile will be deleted from SharePoint on the next synchronization and removed from the index on the next crawl.

Answer (score 0):

The My Site Cleanup Job is responsible for deleting user profiles and My Sites of those users.  This includes the following activities:

1. Remove user profiles that are queued for deletion.
2. If those users have a My Site, assign the  user’s manager as the SPSite.SecondaryContact.  Email the manager letting them know that the user’s My Site will be deleted in 14 days.
3. 11 days after the first notification, email the manager again letting them know that the My Site will be deleted in 3 days.
4. After a total of 14 days, delete the MySite.

source: [Inside the SharePoint 2010 My Site Cleanup Timer Job](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx)